# I'm having an issue with when I'm trying to use umount command to unmount my usb flash drive

Tags: partitioning, usb, mount, virtualbox, umount

I'm using Virtualbox and SEED Ubuntu 16.04.

I'm trying to unmount my flash drive with the command `sudo umount /dev/sdb1`, assuming that my USB is attached as `sdb1`.

However I would get this error saying that it is not mounted:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Mounting and unmounting of removable devices is usually handled by gio/udev or by `udev/gvfs` on older versions - does `gvfs-mount --list` show the device?

Comment: Do not assume sd(x) is what you think it is.  It might have been on last boot, but now can be something else.

Comment: Please include the error as text, not as an image. It is not possible to search an image whereas text is.

Answer (score 0):

The file system on your USB flash drive is likely /dev/sdb1, but the mount point has a name, too.

run the following command

```
    mount | grep sdb1
```

and you will see the name of the mount point.  The mount command should show you the file system /dev/sdb1 and just to the right of it "on " and then the name of the mount point.

Retry your umount command replacing /dev/sdb1 with the name of the mount point instead.

Regards,
mondotofu

Answer (score 0):

### Unmount USB Flash Drive

`sudo umount -lrf /isodevice`

Is what I use to unmount the root partition of a bootable USB device.